# Python splitting data into random sets

Tags: python

I would like to split my data into two random sets. I've done the first part:

```
ind = np.random.choice(df.shape[0], size=[int(df.shape[0]*0.7)], replace=False)
X_train = df.iloc[ind]
```

Now I would like to select all index' not in `ind` to create my test set. Please can you tell me how to do this?

I thought it would be

```
X_test = df.iloc[-ind]
```

but apparently it isn't

Comment: So you want to select 70% as test data and use the rest 30% as training data ? An easier way to do that might be to use np.random.shuffle to shuffle indexes and use first 70% of the shuffled indexes as training and rest as test.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pure-Python approach.

```
ind_inversed = list(set(range(df.shape[0])) - set(ind))
X_test = df.iloc[ind_inversed]
```

Comment: This doesn't randomize the two sets

Comment: It does since I assume `ind` was calculated the same way as in the original question. `ind_inversed` represents all the other indecies not in `ind`.

Comment: I'm getting the Error `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'` with this technique

Comment: @jlt199, I've updated my answer. I've tested this solution, it does work.

Comment: Thank you, this works too. I've selected this one as the approved answer simply because it's the one I have ended up using. The other suggested techniques also work great and no doubt will be used in the future

Answer (score 4):

Check out [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) `test_train_split()`

Example from the docs:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
>>> X
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> list(y)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>>

>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
...
>>> X_train
array([[4, 5],
       [0, 1],
       [6, 7]])
>>> y_train
[2, 0, 3]
>>> X_test
array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9]])
>>> y_test
[1, 4]
```

In your case you could do it like this:

```
larger, smaller = test_train_split(df, test_size=0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get a 70 - 30 train test split would be to generate indices, shuffle them and then split it in 70 - 30 parts.

```
ind = np.arange(df.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(ind)
X_train = df.iloc[ind[:int(0.7*df.shape[0])],:]
X_test = df.iloc[ind[int(0.7*df.shape[0]):],:]
```

I would suggest converting the `pandas.dataframe` to a numeric matrix and using scikit-learn's `train_test_split` to do the splitting unless you really want to do it this way.

Comment: I like this method. Thanks. I've used `train_test_split` before (although I had forgotten about it), but I find the data easier to check and visualise in a dataframe.